# IBM DB2 9 SQL0206N EntityCommandExecutionException [colname] is not valid in the context where it is used

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, db2

I am having trouble with IBM DB2 and .net Entity Framework to work. I am currently trying to get data from DB2 database using EF. This is the code:

```
 using (DBEntities ent = new DBEntities())
 {
    foreach (Company comp in ent.COMPANIES)
    {
       listBox1.Items.Add(comp.Address);
    }
 }
```

I encountered this exception: "EXTENT1.COMPANY_ID" is not valid in the context where it is used. I noticed that my schema is different. It should be CMIS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fluid code, the DbContext you may need to specify the table schema.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Map(m => m.ToTable("MYTABLE", "MYSCHEMA"));
```